# CommandLineRunner won't add roles to users

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm follow a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVn9OG9nfH0) on Spring Boot Security, but I got stuck. Currently I'm setting up a CommandLineRunner, which does 3 things:

- Create Roles
- Create User
- Add roles to users
  Running the code creates a table with the created roles and a table for the created users, but adding roles to users ends up in a error. I checked the code several times but cant find a mistake.

Please check out my code on [Github](https://github.com/LucasHartman/SpringSecurityJWTExampleB/tree/master/src/main/java/com/api/SpringSecurityJWTExampleB) and below you find the Stack overflow . Please let me know if you found something.

```
2022-04-30 10:57:14.987  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain   : Will secure any request with    [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@730805c6
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@bb8b366, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@795dc7e9
 org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2880966c
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@10e422c
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@43e72b5f
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@2f355434
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@3c7e2ca5
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7beec8d4 org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3a0be2ce
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4cdcc103, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@31dbfb96
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5a9db93d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@decd01c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6b29fa07]

2022-04-30 10:57:15.081  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain]
o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-04-30 10:57:15.178  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-04-30 10:57:15.198  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] a.S.SpringSecurityJwtExampleBApplication : Started SpringSecurityJwtExampleBApplication in 12.056 seconds (JVM running for 15.368)
2022-04-30 10:57:15.226  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.S.service.UserServiceImpl            : Saving new role ROLE_USER to user Akatsuki
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_, user0_.username as username4_1_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-04-30 10:57:15.598  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-30 10:57:15.654 ERROR 5620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.api.SpringSecurityJWTExampleB.SpringSecurityJwtExampleBApplication.main(SpringSecurityJwtExampleBApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLaunchr.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 3; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 3
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:385) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy104.findByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.api.SpringSecurityJWTExampleB.service.UserServiceImpl.addRoleToUser(UserServiceImpl.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.api.SpringSecurityJWTExampleB.service.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3409e614.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at com.api.SpringSecurityJWTExampleB.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8ecf556.addRoleToUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.api.SpringSecurityJWTExampleB.SpringSecurityJwtExampleBApplication.lambda$run$0(SpringSecurityJwtExampleBApplication.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:777) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 3
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:198) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

2022-04-30 10:57:15.682  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-04-30 10:57:15.696  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-04-30 10:57:15.712  INFO 5620 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Baz Garcha, I added check before adding the entry to the database, but, when retrieving the entry from the database I got "query did not return a unique result", I solved this by applying unique key constraint on this column @Table(
        name="table",
        uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username"})
) and not a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method userRepo.findByUsername expects a single object to be returned.
User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username)
But you have more than 1 user with same username.

Every time you're running the application it's adding same users again in the DB

1. You can check if user exist before adding it again to DB.
2. Make username primary key.